# VueJS : v-for not rendering

Tags: laravel, vue.js, v-for

I'm trying vueJS (+ laravel) and i'm encountering a problem.

I made an OrdersComponent.vue with a v-for (for each order which I retrieved from my API), but nothing happens

**OrderComponent.vue :** (h1 is rendering, and console.log(this.orders) is working)

```
   <template>
    <div>
        <h1> Commandes </h1>
        <div class="card card-body" v-for="order in orders" v-bind:key="order.idCommande">
            <h2> {{ order.date }} </h2>
            <span> {{ order.statut }} </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            orders: [],
            order: {
                idCommande: '',
                date: '',
                prix: '', 
                statut: '',
            },
            orderId: '',
            edit: false
        }
    },

    methods: {
        fetchOrders() {
            fetch('api/orders')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    this.orders = res.data;
                    console.log(this.orders);
                })
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchOrders();
    }
})
</script>
```

**Page which call the component (orders.blade.php) :**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <orders></orders>
@endsection
```

**finally, layouts.app file :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('./') }}">
                           MyOnlineCV
                        </a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                            </ul>

                            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                                @guest
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                @else
                                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                            {{ Auth::user()->username .' '. Auth::user()->email }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </a>

                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('commandes') }}"> Mes commandes </a>

                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                                {{ __('Logout') }}
                                            </a>

                                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="GET" style="display: none;">
                                                @csrf
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                @endguest
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            <div id="app">
                <div class="container">
                    @yield('content')
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have already fixed it but in my case I was using an arrow function in `methods` but it was not working this way. I had to change it to "normal" function declaration like so:

```
methods: {
    fetchOrders: function() {
        fetch('api/orders').then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.orders = res.data;
            console.log(this.orders);
        });
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this from your component`s data() method:

```
        ...
        order: {
            idCommande: '',
            date: '',
            prix: '', 
            statut: '',
        },
        orderId: '',
        ...
```

You declare "order" in v-for section:

```
v-for="order in orders"
```

Comment: Did you re-compile app after removing order:{...} ?

Comment: @AfrazAhmad Yes i did

Answer (score 0):

**May be you forgot to recompile your app after making change**.

Remove order object from data()

```
 order:{
  idCommande: '',
        date: '',
        prix: '', 
        statut: '',
 }
```

and recompile the app using:

```
npm run dev
```

**Moreover:**
We create this kind of objects when we are going to submit some data using a form.

**For example**

For signup/register, we get user name, email, age, etc and save it into an object like below by calling each value in a template (e.g. user.name)

```
user:{
   name:'',
   email:'',
   age: '',
}
```

and then we just send user object via axios or fetch to the server.

Comment: Yes I recompiled the app after removing the 'order' object, but I stil have the same issue